# How to make object values as `null` or `undefined` if the property not found in the Object using Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

Hi I am having an object like this, I want to return the property values as `undefined` or `null` if not present in the object. Here is my object.

```
var build= { 'ts1': 1, 'ts2': '2', 'ts3': 3 };
```

I am using  `_.pick` function to pick the values it only pick values that are present in the object.
  Here is my code:

```
_.pick(build, [ 'ts0' 'ts1', 'ts2','ts5','ts6','ts7']);
```

I am getting the result like this:

```
 { 'ts1': 1, 'ts2': '2'}
```

and the expected output is:

```
{ 'ts0':null, 'ts1': 1, 'ts2': '2','ts5':null,'ts6':null,'ts7':null}
```

Please can anybody help me on this.

Comment: `_.pick` is designed to give you a subset of the properties of an object. It will not assign a property to `null` that had never existed in the original object.

Comment: @gyre is there any other function which ll resolve my issue.

Comment: You might not need one; see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

`_.pick` is designed to give you a subset of the properties of an object. It will not assign a property to `null` that had never existed in the original object.

However, you mentioned that:

> I want to return the property values as `undefined` or `null` if not present in the object

Luckily for you, JavaScript already does this by default (returning `undefined`) for all property accesses where the property does not exist on the target object. So, you could simply use the code you have already and use regular bracket property access notation to have property values default to `undefined`:

```js
var build = {
  'ts1': 1,
  'ts2': '2',
  'ts3': 3
}

var result = _.pick(build, [
  'ts0', 'ts1', 'ts2', 'ts5', 'ts6', 'ts7'
])

console.log(result['ts0']) //=> undefined
console.log(result['ts1']) //=> 1
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** If you really need the properties to exist on the object and default to `null`, you can use the following method:

```js
var build = {
  'ts1': 1,
  'ts2': '2',
  'ts3': 3
}

var result = _.reduce([
  'ts0', 'ts1', 'ts2', 'ts5', 'ts6', 'ts7'
], function (o, e) {
  o[e] = e in build ? build[e] : null
  return o
}, {})

console.log(result['ts0']) //=> undefined
console.log(result['ts1']) //=> 1
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gyre thanks  for your reply,  but i need it in the object only, i am going to compare this Object for Some other purpose. is there anyway of getting object as expected in the Result.

Comment: @Jeevan I edited in a second option that should do what you asked

Comment: If the only dependency is `_.reduce` you could use `Array.prototype.reduce` instead.

Comment: I normally would; wasn't sure what OP desired in terms of legacy IE support though.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the desired values and build a new object. `_.set` will add the value to the new object. `_.get` will attempt to get the value from the existing object, if it does not exist then it will use `null` as the default value.

```js
var build = {
  'ts1': 1,
  'ts2': '2',
  'ts3': 3
};
var pickValues = ['ts0', 'ts1', 'ts2', 'ts5', 'ts6', 'ts7'];
var result = {};
_.forEach(pickValues, function(key) {
  _.set(result, key, _.get(build, key, null));
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..of` loop to iterate array, assign properties to object, set value to value of `build` at that property, or `null`

```js
var build = { 'ts1': 1, 'ts2': '2', 'ts3': 3 };
let props = ['ts0', 'ts1', 'ts2','ts5','ts6','ts7'];
let res = {};
for (let prop of props) res[prop] = build[prop] || null;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just not how `_.pick` works. You could use `_.assign` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```js
var build = {
  'ts1': 1,
  'ts2': '2',
  'ts3': 3
};

let result = _.assign({
  ts0: null,
  ts1: null,
  ts2: null,
  ts3: null,
  ts4: null,
  ts5: null,
  ts6: null,
  ts7: null
},
build);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Jordan but i can't able to assign like like this, there soo many Property names ll come. i can't able assign it manually.

Comment: Well then @gyre's answer should do it for ya.